# Hibernate, change configuration file name

Tags: hibernate, file, configuration

I need to read the Hibernate configuration properties from a file name different that `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Following code works but is deprecated:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.content.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

But when I try to use the new configuration method:

```
serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

it doesn't work.

How should I get Hibernate to read a different configuration file?

Thank you.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: It doesn't load the hibernate.cfg.xml and the error no hibernate.cfg.xml found arises.

Answer (score 1):

We can use following code

```
configuration = new Configuration();
sessionFactory = configuration.configure("filename.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

Here, filename.cfg.xml should be present in the classpath.